# Serverless - Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined error when running sls deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

By the way, I just need some help with the project I'm working on. For some reason I'm getting `Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined` error I added serverkess-step-functions plugin. Running `sls deploy` will display the error. I don't know what is wrong.

Here is the simplified version of my serverless.yml:

```
service: rh-cron-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: us-east-1
  # timeout: 10
  environment:
    DBHOST: ${self:custom.stageConfig.dbHost}
    DBUSER: ${self:custom.stageConfig.dbUser}
    DBPASSWORD: ${self:custom.stageConfig.dbPassword}
    DBDATABASE: ${self:custom.stageConfig.dbDatabase}
    DBPORT: ${self:custom.stageConfig.dbPort}
    ENV: ${self:provider.stage}
    REGION: ${self:provider.region}
    SERVICE: ${self:service}

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
        - lambda:InvokeAsync
      Resource: "*"

package:
  include:
    - shared/**
    - configs/**
  exclude:
    - venv/**

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-stage-manager
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

custom:
  stageConfig: ${file(configs/stages-config.yml):${self:provider.stage}}
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
  stages: # serverless-stage-manager
    - dev
    - staging
    - prod


functions:
  fetch_property_listings:
    handler: functions.fetch_property_listings.handler

stepFunctions:
  validate: true
  stateMachines:
    RHPropertiesCronMachine:
      name: RHPropertiesCronMachine-${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
      dependsOn: CustomIamRole
      definition:
        Comment: "A State Machine that regularly updates the Realty Hub DB"
        TimeoutSeconds: 900
        StartAt: FetchMLSPropertylisting
        States:
          FetchMLSPropertylisting:
            Type: Task
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt: [fetch_property_listings, Arn]
            Retry:
              - ErrorEquals:
                  - States.ALL
                IntervalSeconds: 5
                MaxAttempts: 3
                BackoffRate: 2
            Next: IsNextLinkAvailable
          IsNextLinkAvailable:
            Type: Choice
            Choices:
              - Variable: "$.isNextLinkAvailable"
                BooleanEquals: true
                Next: DebugTotalItem
            Default: Done
          DebugTotalItem:
            Type: Pass
            Next: FetchMLSPropertylisting
          Done:
            Type: Task
            End: true
```

And this is the stack trace:

```
.Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
 
  Type Error ---------------------------------------------
 
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
      at /mnt/c/dev/realty-hub/mls-cron/serverless/rh-cron-service/node_modules/serverless-step-functions/lib/deploy/stepFunctions/compileIamRole.js:340:59
      at arrayMap (/mnt/c/dev/realty-hub/mls-cron/serverless/rh-cron-service/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:639:23)
      at map (/mnt/c/dev/realty-hub/mls-cron/serverless/rh-cron-service/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9554:14)
      at Function.flatMap (/mnt/c/dev/realty-hub/mls-cron/serverless/rh-cron-service/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9257:26)
      at ServerlessStepFunctions.getIamPermissions (/mnt/c/dev/realty-hub/mls-cron/serverless/rh-cron-service/node_modules/serverless-step-functions/lib/deploy/stepFunctions/compileIamRole.js:298:12)
      at /mnt/c/dev/realty-hub/mls-cron/serverless/rh-cron-service/node_modules/serverless-step-functions/lib/deploy/stepFunctions/compileIamRole.js:385:56
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at ServerlessStepFunctions.compileIamRole (/mnt/c/dev/realty-hub/mls-cron/serverless/rh-cron-service/node_modules/serverless-step-functions/lib/deploy/stepFunctions/compileIamRole.js:378:32)
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.invoke (/home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:490:22)
      at PluginManager.spawn (/home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:510:17)
      at Deploy.<anonymous> (/home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/deploy/deploy.js:115:50)
  From previous event:
      at Object.before:deploy:deploy [as hook] (/home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/deploy/deploy.js:100:30)
      at /home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:490:55
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.invoke (/home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:490:22)
      at /home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:525:24
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.run (/home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:525:8)
      at /home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:133:33
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:137:15)
  From previous event:
      at Serverless.run (/home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:120:74)
      at /home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:82:30
      at /home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:136:16
      at /home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:57:14
      at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:154:23)
  From previous event:
      at /home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:82:8
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:137:15)
  From previous event:
      at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cijhake/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:71:4)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              12.16.1
     Framework Version:         1.67.0
     Plugin Version:            3.5.0
     SDK Version:               2.3.0
     Components Version:        2.22.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been answered [here](https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-step-functions/issues/323) by [@ccampell](https://github.com/ccampell) in Github.

In summary, the error is caused by the `Done` state of my State Machine definition:

```
 Done:
   Type: Task
   End: true
```

It should be `Type: Pass` instead of `Type: Task`. `Task` state requires the `Resource` field, which is missing on my `Done` state definition.